# How to Record and Play the video in HTML5?

Tags: html5-video

I want to record and play the video. I have found the below article to capture the same. but the recorded video is playing so fast and not playing all of the actions. after 32 seconds, it gets reset to starting position.

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/record-user-webm.html

I have used the code from (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-history). I can share it if required.

Any clues to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can any body have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, a reason why the video plays back too fast may be the fact that you are using a resolution that is to high for the current API to handle when recording.

I've tested similar attempts to record video directly in browser and had the same issue with playbacks of recording made with high resolutions.

Maybe this link could help
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

or for an extensive overview of the current state of webRTC you can read the following article:

http://hdfvr.com/html5-video-recording